# Library to parse String content based on rules

Tags: java, html, string-formatting

I want to add custom logic/class to my custom Jackson JsonSerialize implementation such that it parses out html based on certain rules. For example, if html is inclosed in single quotes `'<b>'text'</b>'` then the custom logic should accept the string as is.  If its not in single quotes, like `<b>text</b>` then I want the custom logic/class to return just text.  Additionally, if I have a block of html enclosed in three single quotes `'''<html><head><title>example</title></head></html>'''` it should accepted as is but if its not then only the example text should be returned and everything else parsed out.  What is the best Java library to accomplish this?  I thought about using AnitSamy but that leaves me open to an XSS attack since I need to accept anything inside quotes.

Examples:

```
input:<b>text</b>
output:text

input:'<b>'text'</b>'
output:'<b>'text'</b>'

input:<html><head><title>text</title></head></html>
output:text

input:'''<html><head><title>text</title></head></html>'''
output:'''<html><head><title>text</title></head></html>'''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the Java Regex engine to look for patterns. Ex:

```
p = Pattern.compile("'''[\\w*]'''");
m = p.matcher(input);
if(m.find()){
    //Do some logic
}
```

Here's a link to a Java Regex website:
http://www.regular-expressions.info/java.html